# Can I select hidden HTML radio button using an assigned label?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to get away with murder here, or at least I feel like I am. I am making an HTML calendar that will allow users to choose a day and submit the form to the server side for more processing *without using javascript*. Here is a snippet of my HTML:

```
<body>
    <form action="/Controller/Select" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="day">
                        <div>30</div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="selectedDay" id="selectedDay_2011_10_30" value="2011-10-30" />
                            <label for="selectedDay_2011_10_30">$1.00</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="day">
                        <div>31</div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="selectedDay" id="selectedDay_2011_10_31" value="2011-10-31" />
                            <label for="selectedDay_2011_10_31">$1.00</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="day">
                        <div>1</div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="selectedDay" id="selectedDay_2011_11_01" value="2011-11-01" />
                            <label for="selectedDay_2011_10_01">$1.00</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.day input {
    display: none;
}
```

For good measure here is screenshot of what I am doing both with and w/o the radio buttons hidden:

[image: With radio buttons displayed. (i.e. - display: inline-block;)]

[image: Without the radio buttons displayed. (i.e. - display: none;)]

The idea is that when the user clicks on the label (which is not hidden) the radio button it is attached to via the "for" attribute it will become checked. However, watching the behavior in the Chrome Developer Tools shows no change in the "checked" attribute of the radio button input element.

If I change the CSS to this:

```
.day input {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The radio button is checked every time I click on the label it is associated with. Any ideas? Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Just place the radio button *inside* the label and it will work... (Btw in that case, you won't have to connect them via the `id`/`for` attributes.)

Comment: seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/gBVMW/ and http://jsfiddle.net/gBVMW/1/

Comment: Cute, but it's not a standard UX convention so it may confuse people.

Comment: @JohnB yeah. I'm just prototyping and wanted to test out some ideas. I would eventually show state (what the user selected) using JS.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas thanks for the tip. That will sure cut down on the id's.

Comment: @Joseph weird. Did you happen to try it in the developer tools watching the DOM element properties? I can't get the "checked" attribute/property to change in realtime. Maybe it is just something with the developer tools.

Comment: @Joseph do you want to put your comment as the answer? I'm not sure what to do in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work: (radio box will not be changed when user click another label)

```
.day input {display: none;}
```

This however should work:

```
.day input {visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px;}
```

Comment: Actually, this does work. After receiving feedback from @Joseph I went ahead and implemented the idea. Works like a charm.